# Event propagation on angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, jquery-events

I am implementing a web app using angularjs (first time for me). One of the feature I would like to provide the user with is to create a div in the main window when the user click on an image in the menu.

For that, I have created a directive as shown below.

```
var platform = angular.module('platform', []);
    
platform.directive('addElement', function() {
        
  return function (scope,element, attrs){
        var createElement;
        
        createElement = function(){
            $('<div>Test</div>').appendTo('#body-main-window');
        };

        
        $(this).on('click',createElement);
    } 
});
```

And here is the following html code:

```
<img class = "imgMenu" src="styles/img/logo_add.png" add-element />
```

The problem is that the `onClick` event triggered on an element looks to be propagated to all its ancestors. Indeed, wherever I click on, the div is created. It is not the expected behaviour since the div should be created only when the user click on image where the directive is.

Additionally, when clicking, the directive is executed as many times as there are images with the directive attribute.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/6Ku7D/10/

One solution would be to use the ng-click directive but it will imply doing some DOM modifications within the controller (and it is not the proper way to achieve my goal). Directive is thus the solution but I am getting stuck.

**EDIT (EXTRA INFORMATION)**

Actually, it is just the skeleton of what I want to do. In a nutshell, elements I want to click on are in the menu of my app. These elements are simply names of some objects. By clicking on them, I want to create a div that will not contain only the name  but other information on this object that can be edited. Moreover, the div I will create should be draggable (using jquery-ui) and finally, I should be able to "link" these divs to create a workflow. Actually, what I want to do is something quite similar to [yahoo pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) (providing a user-friendly interface for mashup/workflow edition) but dedicated to researchers in computer science (data mining). Objects will be algorithms, datasets or visualization techniques that have been first imported via a web service I have developped. Consequently, it is not as simple as "adding a value to an existing array". Do you still think I should use ng-click?

Comment: Angular is, by design, "this-less." Your `$(this)`, not sure what you're trying to do there, but you probably want `$(element)`.

Comment: @darkporter Thanks for the advice. I will follow the "this-less" philosophy from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Jquery event issue...

try using stopPropagation() to keep the event from bubbling.

```
platform.directive('addElement', function() {

  return function (scope,element, attrs){
        var createElement;

        createElement = function(e){
            $('<div>Test</div>').appendTo('#body-main-window');
           e.stopPropagation();
        };


        $(this).on('click',createElement);
    } 
});
```

---

**EDIT**

I see what you're trying to do, and [here is a working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/g0ptxe) that does what you're trying to do... that said, I don't think you're going about this the best way.

If you want to add a new value to a list of values in Angular, I think you're going about it the hard way. Then again I don't know what your end goal is... but try this instead:

[Here's a plunk for my suggested solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/xP2NWk)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
    <div id="menu">
        <div ng-repeat="item in listTest" class="toAddIcon" ng-click="addResult()">
            {{item}}, click here to add a div to results
        </div>                          
    </div>

    <hr/>
    <div id="displayResult"> 
        <header> -- Results -- </header>   
        <div ng-repeat="result in results">{{result}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.listTest = ['Peter','Bob','Susan'];   
  $scope.results = [];

  $scope.addResult = function(){
    $scope.results.push('TEST');
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the line you suggested but the problem is still present.

Comment: I've changed my answer a bit to show how I would have done the directive declaration. If this doesn't work, you'll have to post a fiddle or some more complete code so I can see what's happening that you don't like.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my post to post a fiddle. The fiddle is very similar to what I want to do (except that I am calling a restful web service to feed the array). But apparently the directive is not recognized in the fiddle (nothing happen when I click) whereas it is in my code...

Comment: I've updated my answer with ... TWO answers. One that does exactly what you were trying to do; And one that does what you were trying to do in an easier "more angular" way.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have updated my question to add some extra pieces of information regarding my application needs. Could you have a look and tell me if the ng-click solution is still preferable?

Comment: Yes, the ng-click solution will still be preferable for the adding of elements in an "angular way".

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. But I have a question: I've read that manipulating DOM within the controller is not the good thing to do. So, if inserting and modifying "complex elements" (nested divs, forms) in the page is not DOM manipulation, what is it actually?

Comment: Using JavaScript to create or change DOM elements or bind events is "DOM Manipulation".  What your controller is supposed to be doing is modifying data structures in your $scope... Then Angular handles all DOM manipulation via directives.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you very much for your clear explanations.It was really helpful. I will think about my application design accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ng-click. I don't know why this implies to do DOM manipulation by a controller:

```
var platform = angular.module('platform', []);

platform.directive('addElement', function() {

  return function (scope,element, attrs){

        scope.createElement = function(){
            $('<div>Test</div>').appendTo('#body-main-window');
        };

    } 
});
```

HTML code:

```
<img class="imgMenu" src="styles/img/logo_add.png" add-element ng-click="createElement()" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question to add some extra pieces of information regarding my application needs. Could you have a look and tell me if the ng-click solution is still preferable?

Comment: I would still go for ng-click(). First it is the easiest way (as far as I know) and you can add unlimited amount of extra processing inside of your directive OR you simply add a template which contains even new directives. For draggability I would for example create an extra directive that simply makes the host element of the directive draggable (this way you could easily make other things draggable as well). In conclusion I don't know of anything why you shouldn't use ng-click :)

Comment: I would also use the $compile function to add HTML elements to the DOM as they are not part of the scope otherwise. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile